# Javascript periodically getting the last row of mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL database which has co-ordinates saved in it. I  want to display those on a Google map using  java-script and php. What i basically have to do is extract the last row from the database after every 3 second and update my marker position on the map.

The problem that i am encountering is that when i call my php function in java-script, it is called only once when the page loads. After that it does not call it and the subsequent values added in the database are not shown.

How do i periodically get the last row from the database to my java-script?

Edit:
The following code updates the div only once, function gets called every second but the value returned by the php function is always the same.

```
<html>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","*****","*****","gps");

function getLast(){
         $sql = "
                 SELECT longitude 
                      , latitude     
                   FROM gpstable
                  ORDER 
                     BY id DESC
                  LIMIT 1;
                ";

         $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sql);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

         $longi=$row[0];
         $lati = $row[1];
         return $longi .','. $lati;
}
?>


<script>
var t =setInterval(function(){changeDivContent()},1000);

function changeDivContent(){
        var phpadd= <?php echo getLast(); ?>;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = phpadd;
}
</script>


<body>
        <div id="content">ABC</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now change your password.

Comment: If you're okay with a jQuery solution you could have the PHP on a different page and use jQuery to load it into an element. Here is an [example on w3fools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load)

Comment: You can't run anything like this. You need to get values with AJAX and return them back. Then you can use them as you wish. Please look at this page : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the JavaScript function :

```
setInterval(function() {
    /* ajax code to get the last coodinate */
}, 3000);
```

Edit :
You edited your question.
Everytime your changeDivContent() function is called, the same value will go into "phpadd".

You have to connect to the database each time you want to do a query in PHP.

Maybe you could create a PHP file which returns the last coordinate (in any format, like JSON or HTML). And in the main file, you call the other file with Ajax to get the last coordinates.

According to the comment of Moob, setTimeout is better :

```
function myFunction()
{
    /* code here */
    setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
}

myFunction();
```

An example of what you could do with JQuery (don't know in JavaScript) :

```
<?php

// getCoordinatesAjax.php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","*****","*****","gps");

$sql = "SELECT longitude, latitude FROM gpstable ORDER BY id DESCLIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0] .','. $row[1];




<!-- main.php -->

<script>

    function myFunction()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "getCoordinatesAjax.php"
        })
        .done(function(html) {
            $("#content").append(html);
        });

        setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
    }

    myFunction();

</script>
```

Comment: FYI setInterval is a little risky. What if your function takes more than the interval to complete? Better to use setTimeout and have the function call itself after it completes.